# Restart Manager Dialog Localizing Partially for Wix Installer

Tags: wix, windows-installer, wix3.11, installshield-2014, windows-restart-manager

We have a legacy InstallShield installer for a product, for which we are porting that product to wix installer.

I observed a improper behavior of localization in Restart Manager dialog only during ARP uninstallation, for which only the description part is getting localized and below radio buttons text is not localized. Screenshot at the end.

But in the InstallShield installer it was proper. I couldn't trace what was missing here in my wix installer for this inconsistent behavior.

I tried checking whether this Restart Manager dialog localization strings will come from Wix or OS.

I tried checking this dialog strings whether available in string table in InstallShield installer but couldn't find it. Neither in WixUI_en-us.wxl in Wix.

So my understanding was this dialog comes from OS, but the question arises why it only partially gets localized.

I had customized the "WixUI_InstallDir" in my installer as below.

```
<UI Id="WixUI_InstallDir1">
```

So I included the below MsiRMFilesInUse dialog in WixUI_InstallDir1.

```
<DialogRef Id="MsiRMFilesInUse" />
```

By including this, the Files In Use dialog is visible and gets localized when uninstalling from MSI, but Restart Manager is partially localized when uninstalling from ARP.

I expect the Restart Manager dialog to be fully localized but the below radio button texts are not getting localized. Screenshot attached below.

[image]

Comment: One question: are you running on a Spanish machine when that un-localized message shows up? If not, please try that first.

Comment: I already tried, irrespective of the OS lang, the below details were always in english.

Comment: Sources on github.com?

Comment: Just wondering, what result do you get if you use dialog set `<UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />`?

Comment: We can't use other Wix UI styles apart from InstallDir, please suggest what went wrong here.

Comment: Hard to tell without the sources or the MSI in question. Also: checking with WixUI_Mondo was suggested to determine if there is something wrong with the particular dialog set you are using. If you can test quickly that is good information. Generally English shows up as a fallback language (when the requested language for the string in question is not available). Those options come from the Restart Manager feature of windows, I guess there could be issues with that - not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried WixUI_Mondo, still same partial localization is only happening in that case also. If it comes from OS and not installer, still question is why partial localization. Where does the strings of RestartManager dialog come from, really from Installer only I guess, please correct me?

Comment: Please do reply

Comment: Using `Orca` - if you open the compiled MSI and look in the table `"RadioButton"`. What does it say in the `Text column`? Is the text localized or in English?

Comment: The strings inside MSI in radiobutton table are the one's which come in MsiRMFilesInUse dialog but not the strings in RestartManager dialog.

Comment: Please do reply

Comment: Use `MsiTran` instead of `torch` tool to generate language transform files.